# SQLAlchemy create engine with echo=True from config file

Tags: sqlalchemy

I just want to know how to create the engine with the config file that would give the same result as:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydb.sqlite', echo=True)
```

I think it would be with a `config.py` file like

```
DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///oracle.sqlite'
```

and

```
import config
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import database_exists, drop_database

engine = create_engine(config.DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
```

for creating the database every time it's needed. For deleting:

```
if database_exists(config.DATABASE_URL):
    drop_database(engine.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config = {'db.url':'sqlite:///./somedb.db', 'db.echo':'True'}
engine = engine_from_config(config, prefix='db.')
```

You can have the config outside the file, and import it!

Also check this out, on [SQLAlchemy Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html?highlight=config%20file#sqlalchemy.engine_from_config).

Comment: If I only need the url I would do `config['db.url']` right?

Comment: Yes, Btw if you redefine that, then you have to redefine engine as well

Answer (score -1):

If you want to capture sql commands, see statistics, find slowest, check [sqlalchemy-capture-sql](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-capture-sql/) (**Disclaimer**: I am the author of the package):

```
from sqlalchemy_capture_sql import CaptureSqlStatements
with CaptureSqlStatements(sqlalchemy_engine) as capture_stmts:
    # put here calls to functions that issue sqlalchemy commands that
    # produce some sql statements execution
    session.add(user)
capture_stmts.pp()
```

the library will make full report, for instance:

```
============================================================
  1. 0.0020 INSERT INTO users (name, fullname, nickname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
     <- 'joe+Joe Joey+joey'
  2. 0.0009 SELECT FROM users  WHERE users.id = ?
     <- '2'
  ...
============================================================
== Slowest (top 5):
      1. INSERT USERS             1   0.002 s INSERT INTO users (name, fullname, nickname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
      2. INSERT USERS             1   0.001 s INSERT INTO users (name, fullname, nickname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
      ...
============================================================
== By sql command (top 20):
    INSERT               2   0.003 s
    SELECT               4   0.003 s
============================================================
== By table (top 20):
    USERS                6   0.007 s
    ...
============================================================
== By sql command + table (top 20):
    INSERT USERS             2   0.003 s
    SELECT USERS             2   0.002 s
    ...
== Totally captured 8 statement(s) in 0.008866 s
```